# number input with UiPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my use case I would like to add in numbers consisting of 4 digits, like in the image. The first digit should be 0 or 1.

My code so far is:

```
func numberOfComponents(in weightPickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return loopingMargin * numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return numbers[row % numbers.count]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    digits[component] = row % numbers.count
    let weightString = "\(digits[0])\(digits[1])\(digits[2])\(digits[3])"
    weightField.text = weightString
}
```

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     if(component == 0)
     {
        return 2
     }
     else
     {
       return loopingMargin * numbers.count
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering:

```
let numbers = [2,10,10,10]
var digits = [0,0,0,0]
```

Update your delegate methods like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers[component]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return String(row)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    digits[component] = row
    let weightString = "\(digits[0])\(digits[1])\(digits[2])\(digits[3])"
    weightField.text = weightString
}
```